# Issue when drawing OnGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent

I'm having an issue when trying to draw a texture on the GUI. Here's the faulty snippet within `OnGUI()`:

```
    var e = Event.current;
    if (e.type == EventType.mouseDown)
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse pressed");
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(e.mousePosition.x, e.mousePosition.y, 100, 110), ButtonTexture);
    }
```

I'm successfully getting the log output but no texture is drawn. However if I use this outside of the `if` statement the texture follow my mouse without any issues. I've been messing around with this for two hours but can't seem to figure out what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: It seems any kind of drawing doesn't work if the condition is an event, however no issues with a standard `if(1>0)`. I've also tried using `Input.GetMouseDown` as an alternative but same issue.

Comment: what happens when you `Debug.Log(e.mousePosition);`

Comment: I'm getting the correct position of the mouse, no issues. Again, everything goes smoothly if I use the same `DrawTexture` outside of the `if` statement.

Comment: what happens if you declare `Rect rect = new Rect(e.mousePosition.x, e.mousePosition.y, 100, 110);` *outside* of the `if` statement, then `GUI.DrawTexture(rect, ButtonTexture);` inside ?

Comment: If you call GUI draw functions during events other than `Repaint`, does it actually draw? The docs don't provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is probably because mouseDown is fired once per mouse click.

[Event.Current](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html) will show the current event that is processing, which could be many different things per frame, so between calls to OnGUI this will probably change.

A better approach would be to store when mousedown event occurs and keep track until it is released, you could approach this by inspecting [Event.Current](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Event-current.html) or this [Input.GetMouseButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html).

Here is a short sample of how you could track whether the mouse is down using Event.Current.

```
bool isMouseDown = false;

void OnGUI()
{
    EventType currentEventType = Event.current.type;

    if (currentEventType == EventType.MouseDown)
    {
        isMouseDown = true;
    }
    else if (currentEventType == EventType.MouseUp)
    {
        isMouseDown = false;
    }

    //Use isMouseDown as appropriate...
}
```